# Vaadin and Spring Security: "/VAADIN/**" route

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin, vaadin8

I have an application with Vaadin 8 and Spring Boot. Currently, I'm in progress of adding authentication to this app. So, I enabled Spring Security and started tinkering with it. Basically, I followed this tutorial: https://vaadin.com/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security/setting-up-spring-security

The approach, described there, works fine, however, I'm slightly disturbed by the fact that `/VAADIN/**` path needs to be publicly available (otherwise, Vaadin doesn't work). I mean, of course, I have protected particular pages by their paths (e.g. `/admin`) and unauthenticated users won't be able to open them, but isn't exposure of `/VAADIN/**` path dangerous? What if some hijacker tries to send some request to the Vaadin servlet outside of the UI (by simply `curl`ing it) with some specific headers/parameters? Is it possible that by formatting such request in some malicious way, the data will be actually returned to this hacker, bypassing Spring Security?

Comment: If you have no "public" facing Vaadin (parts) and your Login is not using Vaadin (e.g. the spring form), you can set the Vaadin-Enpoints to authenticated and don't have to compromise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but isn't exposure of /VAADIN/** path dangerous

It is not dangerous per ce. The framework itself has just some generic parts there, like static resources for the client, like the widgetset and theme. Having said that, it is of course to be noted it application design. For example you should not put something that includes confidential info in your app as ThemeResource, but use ClassResource instead and things like that.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand the concept here, but isn't it also used for processing RPC calls from the UI? Like, if I expand a tree node or smth, there's a call processed by the backend, right? And if the entry point for this call is not protected, then one can mimic such call to retrieve restricted information?

Comment: That is not possible because there is secure token etc. and you should use the app via https only.